# How To get 2 Flat list To attract instead of repel

Tags: react-native, styles, react-native-flatlist

So I am working on a react native project and have created a modal.
this modal shows the selected and unselected Tasks. Now For this I created a View With two flat lists as shown:

```
<View style={styles.tasksListContainer}>
  <FlatList
    data={tasksToShow}
    renderItem={(itemData) => {
      if (!itemData.item.usedUp) {
        return <TaskIsNotBeingUsed itemData={itemData} onTaskSelect={onTaskSelect}/>
      }
    }}
  />
  <FlatList
    data={tasksToShow}
    renderItem={(itemData) => {
      if (itemData.item.usedUp) {
        return <TaskIsBeingUsed itemData={itemData}/>
      }
    }}
  />
</View>
```

Now the problem is that all the Selected Tasks And None Selected Tasks have some kind of space between them can anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using the same array and sometimes return something but sometimes return nothing so there's empty items. You can do it like that:

```
// Unchecked
<FlatList
    data={tasksToShow.filter(itemData => !itemData.usedUp)}

// Checked
<FlatList
    data={tasksToShow.filter(itemData => itemData.usedUp)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `style={{ flexGrow: 0 }}` on your FlatLists to prevent them from growing to fill the space.

However, this solution has certain drawbacks (eg. both lists scroll independently, and once the top one grows too large the bottom one will be pushed off screen).

A `SectionList` would be better suited for this purpose:

```
    <View style={styles.tasksListContainer}>
      <SectionList
        sections={[
          { title: 'being used', data: tasksToShow.filter(el => el.usedUp)},
          { title: 'not being used', data: tasksToShow.filter(el => !el.usedUp)}
        ]}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return item.usedUp
            ? <TaskIsBeingUsed itemData={itemData}/>
            : <TaskIsNotBeingUsed itemData={itemData} onTaskSelect={onTaskSelect}/>
        }}
      />
    </View>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply .Intresting in that case you are right a section list would be perfect.